# How to pass parameters to call R function using subprocess in python

Tags: python, r, parameters

I am trying to call an R funciton using subprocess in python. As example below, how can I pass the "input" and "output" string to call R function rtest?

Thank you!

```js
##python
cmd = ['C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0\\bin\\RScript.exe','C:\\R\\testR.R']
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)



##R testR.R
rtest = function(input="", output=""){
  in_p <- input
  
  ou_p <- output 
  
  outpath<-paste(ou_p,in_p,sep='') #path of the output model and its name
  
  return(outpath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add any additional commandline arguments to the cmd list:

```
cmd = ['C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.0\\bin\\RScript.exe','C:\\R\\testR.R', input, output]
```

and call `subprocess` as you would normally. Note that `rpy2` might an interesting alternative which provides a more direct connection between R and Python.

Comment: Thank you. But testR.R is a file, not a function. If this file have many functions, how can it know what the input and output parameter belong to? How can I call the function rtest(input,output)?

Comment: For that you need rpy2. Just look up the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, rpy2 is a good way to pass parameter to R. I have tried rpy2. But it says there is a memory problem. So even rpy2 is a good way, I still wonder if we can do that using command.